# Are Oracle SQL Optimizer Hints applicable to SSIS?

Tags: sql, oracle, ssis, odbc, optimizer-hints

I have added a `SELECT /*+USE_CONCAT*/` at my query. I found great difference at SQL Developer (only top 200 rows) but I can't say that I found the same improvement at SSIS. Maybe that's because of the huge number of the returned records but I also have a suspicious that `/*+USE_CONCAT*/` is considered as a comment. Does anyone know more about it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: My guess is that it is dependent upon the implementation of the  "database connection manager provider thing" as to whether it does any local parsing or passes it along as is. Easiest way would be to hook the Oracle equivalent of profiler and see what the supplied query looks like

Comment: find your SQL ID for your query as it's running in SSIS, then get the plan using dbms_xplan, then you can see if it's honoring the hint or not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I found out, hints are totally applicable.